# Swift - Character is not a subtype of string

Tags: string, variables, swift, character, subtype

```
myText = "word 1 / word 2"    
var testVar = split(myText, { $0 == "/"}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

This code works but it takes empty space "word 1 " when I use testVar[0]

when I write empty spaces

```
var testVar = split(myText, { $0 == " / "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)
```

I get an error: 'Character' is not a subtype of 'String'

Anyone who knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split()` function only works on Swift strings by comparing each element of the string as a `Character`. To use a string to split a string, use `.componentsSeparatedByString`:

```
var testVar = myText.componentsSeparatedByString(" / ")
```

Comment: Also, for future reference, the last two parameters of `split` have default values, so you can just leave them out: `var testVar = split(myText, { $0 == "/" })`